# How to add a row on button click?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/javalover_stackoverflow/eEru9/7/) there is an add *timing button*. There is default row having week day dropdown,from time textfield,to time textfield and hospital drop down.Now when I click on the add timing button I want another row having week day dropdown,from time textfield,to time textfield and hospital dropdown.

Can any body please tell me how to do that?

This is my knockout code

```
var DocSchedule = function (id, day, fromtime, totime, hospital, hospitalId) {
    this.id = ko.observable(id);
    this.day = ko.observable(day);
    this.fromtime = ko.observable(fromtime);
    this.totime = ko.observable(totime);
    this.hospital = ko.observable(hospital);
    this.hospitalId = ko.observable(hospitalId);
};

var Patientp = function () {
    this.id = ko.observable(idValue);
    this.name = ko.observable(nameValue);
    this.degree = ko.observable(degreeValue);
    this.gender = ko.observable(genderValue);
    //this.consultant= ko.observableArray(consultantArrValue);
    this.username = ko.observable(usernameValue);
    this.password = ko.observable(passwordValue);
    this.email = ko.observable(emailValue);
    this.mobile = ko.observable(mobileValue);
    this.imgFile = ko.observable(imgFileValue);
    this.imgSrc = ko.observable(imgSrcValue);
    this.imagePath = ko.observable(imagePathValue);
    this.userid = ko.observable(useridValue);
    this.department = ko.observable(departmentValue);
    //this.consultant= ko.observableArray(consultantArrValue);
    //this.consultant= ko.observable(consultantValue);
    this.addSlot = function (doctor) {


        var docSchedule = new DocSchedule();
        iter = iter + 1;
        docSchedule.id(iter);

    }


}
idValue = 'hi';
useridValue = 'hi';
nameValue = 'hi';
addressValue = 'adress';
genderValue = 'hi';
mobileValue = 'hi';
//these fields are not available
usernameValue = 'hi';
passwordValue = 'hi';
emailValue = 'hi';
imgFileValue = 'imagefileValue';
imgSrcValue = 'ui_resources/img/profile_pic.png';
imagePathValue = 'imagePathValue';
consultantArrValue = null; //'${currentpatient.user.name}';
consultantValue = "d1";
degreeValue = 'hi';
departmentValue = 'hi';



var iter = 0;
var patp = new Patientp();
ko.applyBindings(patp);
```

Comment: Have you checked any of the examples on the knockout webpage? There are plenty of examples simpler and more complex showing this exact use case like: http://knockoutjs.com/examples/contactsEditor.html...

Comment: @nemesv yes,I have tried and yes I have seen that too but I do not why that another row is not appearing.

Comment: You need an observable array http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html and the foreach binding http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html the documentation of the foreach also contains an example about how to add items to a list...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You don't have `observableArray` schedules in `Patientp` `doctor.schedules.push(docSchedule);`
   throws *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push'* *of undefined*

Try this:

```
var iter = 0;
var DocSchedule = function (id, day, fromtime, totime, hospital, hospitalId) {
    this.id = ko.observable(id);
    this.day = ko.observable(day);
    this.fromtime = ko.observable(fromtime);
    this.totime = ko.observable(totime);
    this.hospital = ko.observable(hospital);
    this.hospitalId = ko.observable(hospitalId);
};

var Patientp = function () {
    this.id = ko.observable(idValue);
    this.name = ko.observable(nameValue);
    this.degree = ko.observable(degreeValue);
    this.gender = ko.observable(genderValue);
    this.username = ko.observable(usernameValue);
    this.password = ko.observable(passwordValue);
    this.email = ko.observable(emailValue);
    this.mobile = ko.observable(mobileValue);
    this.imgFile = ko.observable(imgFileValue);
    this.imgSrc = ko.observable(imgSrcValue);
    this.imagePath = ko.observable(imagePathValue);
    this.userid = ko.observable(useridValue);
    this.department = ko.observable(departmentValue);
    this.schedulers = ko.observableArray([]);
}
idValue = 'hi';
useridValue = 'hi';
nameValue = 'hi';
addressValue = 'adress';
genderValue = 'hi';
mobileValue = 'hi';
usernameValue = 'hi';
passwordValue = 'hi';
emailValue = 'hi';
imgFileValue = 'imagefileValue';
imgSrcValue = 'ui_resources/img/profile_pic.png';
imagePathValue = 'imagePathValue';
consultantArrValue = null;
consultantValue = "d1";
degreeValue = 'hi';
departmentValue = 'hi';

function vm() {
    var self = this;
    self.person = new Patientp();
    self.schedule = new DocSchedule();
    self.schedules = ko.observableArray([new DocSchedule(iter)]);

    self.addSlot = function () {
        console.log('added');
        iter++;
        var docSchedule = new DocSchedule(iter);
        self.schedules.push(docSchedule);
    };

    self.removeSlot = function () {
        console.log('removed');
        self.schedules.remove(this);
    }
};
var viewModel = new vm();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById('addDoctorSchedules'));
```

### Here is the **<kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Hx6Ce/)</kbd>**

Comment: Thanks for answering,I was trying myself and did not succeed so posted here the question but for got to remove doctor.schedules.push(docSchedule);

Comment: What you want exactly. in the fiddle  there is Week Day,From Time, To Time, Available hospital, you want to add them as row from the user input

Comment: when I press add timing then I want another row containing weekday,fromtime,totime,hospital.If I press another time add timing button then another row will be created

Comment: I am waiting for your answer

Comment: I'm working on that please wait, its raining here and electricity is gone i'l update when it's over.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51927/discussion-between-aneesh-a-e-and-jquerylearner)

Comment: I am facing problem,can you help me please?